# When you are writing a comment, returns are taken into account but don't count towards length

Tags: bug, status-declined, comments, character-limit

If you are writing a comment a return is taken into account for the length necessary to make a comment, but if you try to make a comment of 15 returns, it complains about length.

Basically, its just a small mismatch into the real time validation and the actual validation necessary.

Comment: How are you entering return characters?

Comment: Shift + enter is how I do a return

Comment: Next question: *why* are you entering return characters?

Comment: Hah.  A fair question.  I was commenting on a post and noticed it took out my sweet carriage returns when I posted.  It wasn't a case of me doing 15 returns and not being able to comment :-D.  Afterwards I started testing the limits and realized the js validation said a post was OK with 15 returns, which is incorrect because it doesn't allow it.

Comment: I
didn't
think
you
could still do this.  (I used five shift-returns in the previous sentence, but the formatting didn't change, so it's pointless to use them).

Answer (score 4):

The proper answer for this bug report can be represented in a few links:

[http://www.amazon.com/Would-Kill-Stop-Doing-That/dp/B00BJXYTDQ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BJXYTDQ)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02opWiAWNbU

[image: STOP]

[image: DOING]

Comment: The 15 returns was an edge case to demonstrate the fact that there are two different validation mechanisms.  I haven't fully tested it, is it possible one validation allows full Unicode while the other only allows English? Ide guess its two JS functions that should be written as a single one.

Comment: You're arguing against my obviously contrived example and completely ignoring my point which is clearly stated at the bottom of my post.